# passing a parameter in awk command won't work

Tags: bash, awk, terminal

I run the script bellow with `./command script.sh 11`, the first line of code bellow stores the output (321) successfully in parameter x (checked with echo on line 2). On line 3 I try to use parameter x to retrieve the last two columns on all lines where the value in the first column is equal to x (in doc2.csv). This won't work but when I replace `z=$x` by `z=321`it works fine. Why won't this code work when passing the parameter?

```
#!/bin/bash
x="$(awk -v y=$1  -F\; '$1 == y' ~/Documents/doc1.csv | cut -d ';' -f2)"
echo $x
awk -v z=$x -F, '$1 == z' ~/Documents/doc2.csv | cut -d ',' -f2,3
```

doc1.csv (all columns have unique values)

```
33;987
22;654
11;321
...
```

doc2.csv

```
321,156843,ABCD
321,637253,HYEB
123,256843,BHJN
412,486522,HDBC
412,257843,BHJN
862,256843,BHLN
...
```

Comment: Why are you using `cut`? Output jus the column you want in `awk`: `'$1 == y { print $2 }'`.

Comment: Do either of your CSV files use DOS line endings?

Comment: You almost certainly have some kind of white space at the end of each line in the first file so `x` isn't `321` its `321<white space>` and as @chepner says that's quite likely control-Ms so run dos2unix or similar on the files first. Also, you never need cut or grep or sed or any of those other small tools when you're using awk. Read Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: The problem was caused by the dos line endings indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have mentioned there is probably some extra characters coming along for the ride in field 2 of your cut command.

If you just use awk to print the column you want instead of the entire line and cutting that you shouldn't have any problems.  If you still do then you will need to look into `dos2unix`.

```
n=33;
x=$(awk -v y=$n  -F\; '$1 == y {print $2}' d1);
echo ${x};
awk -v z=$x -F, '$1 == z' d2
```

`d1` and `d2` contain doc1 and doc2 contents as you outlined.

As you can see all I did was stop using cut on the output of awk and just told awk to print the second field if the first field is equal to the input variable.

By the way awk is pretty powerful if you weren't aware... You can do this entire program within awk.

```
n=11; awk -v x=$n -F\; 'NR==FNR{ if($1==x){ y[$2]; } next}  $1 in y{print $2, $3}' d1 <( sed 's/,/;/g' d2)
```

`NR==FNR` Is a trick that effectively says "If we are still in the first file, do this"... the key is not forgetting to use `next` to skip the rest of the awk command.  Once we get to the second file `FNR` flips back to 1 but `NR` keeps incrementing up so they'll never be equal again.

So for the first file we just load up the second column values into an array where the first column matches our passed variable.  You could optimize this since you said d1 was always unique lines.

So once we get into the next file the logic skips everything and runs `$1 in y`.  This just checks if the first column is in the array we have created.  If it is awk prints column 2 and 3.

`<( sed 's/,/;/g' d2)` just means we want to treat the output of the sed command as a file.  The sed command is just converting the commas in d2 to semicolons so that it matches the `FS` that awk expects.

Hopefully you've learned a bit about awk, read more here http://www.catonmat.net/blog/ten-awk-tips-tricks-and-pitfalls/ and a great redirection cheat sheet is available here http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf .